# Paragliding late afternoon/sunset available in Interlaken, Switzerland (Bernese Alps)?

Tags: switzerland, adventure, alps, parachutes-skydiving, jungfrau-region

Of course a crown jewel to any visit to the Alps is ascending the "Top of Europe" via Europe's highest train route, Jungfraujoch. [image] 
 However, I only have one full day in the Interlaken area, and I would like to go paragliding in one of the most picturesque places in the world. I've never been paragliding before, and if I do it, there's no better place than in Interlaken, right? 
[image]

I hear mornings are best for viewing the glacier/train/mountain because it tends to be a bit clearer. So in order to squeeze in both... I'd do the train in the morning and hopefully paragliding afterwards. **But do paragliding companies take people in the late afternoons? Is it safe (or even an option) to go paragliding later in the day (late afternoon/sunset)?** *I will be there June 14th which is a Thursday.*

Comment: Due to your very specific constraints I feel this question falls into the WANTA category. You'll have better luck by contacting a tour agency directly IMHO. Also, the "is it worth it" parts of the question can't really be answered on Travel since they're opinion based.

Comment: @JoErNanO, thank you for your tips! I edited my question so it's not opinion-based. It's a question of availability and safety of paragliding at a particular time.

Comment: Splendid. Reopened. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Butterfly and Bones,
There was/were, at least in 2011/2012 season, a paragliding operator or two operating in or near Mürren, which is just above Lauterbrunnen at the foot of Jungfrau massif.

Can't remember their name(s) but I saw their advertising posters somewhere in the area when I was there.

If they are still in business, you may have to compromise/negotiate on the exact time of day. It may depend, to an extent, on the prevailing winds to get sufficient lift or the weather. The gliders I saw flying were about at 2 - 3 p.m., skiing down the slopes behind Mürren and taking off over the Lauterbrunnen valley.

Suggest you try some research on Google, e,g., say, paragliding+muerren+Lauterbrunnen and make some enquiries with them, if you get any hits.

I didn't do any paragliding myself, but it looked like an absolutely awesome adventure to kill some time before returning to Interlaken.

By the way, you can be equally lucky for weather on the Jungfraujoch in both morning and afternoon. I had good weather up there in both a.m. and p.m. on different days. Just luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yea this can most likely be arranged in that region I used to do adventure sports there with funny farm as the organisers they are great, they can help with all sorts of setups in that region at very reasonable prices